# How to safely determine whether a block-scoped variable is defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If the initializer of a `const` or `let` variable throws an error, accessing that variable throws a `ReferenceError` -- **even when checking its type via `typeof`**.

```js
// Foo.js
class Foo { constructor() { /* Something goes wrong and throws... */ } }

const gFoo = new Foo(); // Throws an error
```

```js
// Elsewhere...
console.log(typeof gFoo);  // throws ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

Is there another way to test whether `gFoo` was successfully initialized, or do I have to wrap a `typeof` check in a `try`/`catch` block?

```js
let isInitialized = false;
try {
  if (typeof foo != 'undefined')
    isInitialized = true;
} catch (e) {}  // ugly but it works
```

Mainly, I'm surprised that [`typeof` can throw a ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#errors).

Comment: How does the first one exactly produce ReferenceError it does not for me

Comment: Your code makes no sense, any line after the first is not executed due to the exception on the first.

Comment: The much more interesting question would be: In what scenario would one ever need such a check?

Comment: Are you testing this code in a browser console or something? Your first example is incorrect and would only behave that way if you're running it one line at a time. The answer to your questions is  "Don't write code that could execute in an order where any of this matters".

Comment: I've updated the example to be more realistic. In my motivating example, a global variable is created, but its constructor might throw.

Anyone who wants to use the global variable must check whether it exists, which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an error is thrown, the execution of the current function stops (the statements after throw won't be executed), and control will be passed to the first catch block in the call stack. At that point, the variable doesn't get initialised, causing the ReferenceError exception.

So to answer your question, whenever you know there are possible errors thrown, make sure to always wrap it within try catch blocks.

With your case above, since the error could happen within the function assigned to foo, you should have the try catch block there; Something like:

```js
const foo = (() => { 
  try {
    // Do whatever
    throw Error();
    // return value to assign to foo
  } catch(err) {
    // Log error for monitoring
    // return undefined
  }
})();

if (foo) { 
  // Do something with foo
} else {
  // Do something if foo errored
}
```

Comment: My original example was wrong, but I think this solution will work for my new example as well -- the global variable in my example shouldn't be assigned to the value of the constructor, but to the value of an anonymous function that tries to return an instance, like in your answer.

It's certainly less ugly that having all the users of the global variable use try/catch to test whether the variable exists.